# Can you please explain differences in following phrases:

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, progressive-aspect

Can you please explain differences in following phrases:

- I am thinking
- I thinking
- I think
- I have been thinking

Comment: on math we have a phrase - can you show what you have done? the second one is plain wrong, unless you add a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **I am thinking**
  This is present tense. You currently thinking at this precise moment.
- **I thinking**
  This is not the correct usage of English. I would presume it was heard as the incorrect version of the above.
- **I think**
  This version precedes your opinion. For example, "I think there will be further welfare cuts in the budget."
- **I have been thinking**
  This variant is past-tense. You have considered a topic and are reflecting upon it.